# Issue creating a user using bootstrap_form_for. (I am using devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I have a two fold question. First, I am not sure I am using the bootstrap_form_for correctly. this is what I currently have

```
       <%= bootstrap_form_for(@user,  :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>

        <%
=begin%>
 <%= f.text_field :name, 
                           placeholder: 'username (will be shown publicly)', 
                           class: 'form-control' %> 
<%
=end%>
        <%= f.text_field :email, 
                           placeholder: 'email', 
                           class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, 
                              placeholder: 'password', 
                              class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, 
                              placeholder: 'password confirmation', 
                              class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.submit 'Sign up', class: 'btn sign-up-button' %>
      <% end %>
```

And this form is to match this setup:

```
 create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "name", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

I am using devise for this project which i am not too privy on but am trying to learn. 
I also currently have the name text field commented out because when I had this up and running in rails and I click on 'sign up' from the home page I get this error back

```
NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new
```

and

```
undefined method `name' for #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I comment out the code and I can render the form just fine, however, once I enter all my information, the screen jumps to the login screen, which is what I do want, but it does not create the user.

I enter the information I had just put in and the password field clears and thats that.What is it that I am missing? Anything else I need to show here I will to bring a better understanding. Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there any error in the logs when you submit?

Comment: `form_for` actually requires the object to actually respond to the method. Did you forget to run a migration that adds the `users.name` column to the database or is it actually `users.username`?